# argument of type is not iterable or how to find substring in logger responce

Tags: python, watchdog

I trying to do something when file with extension appears in folder. I am using watchdog but it doesn't let me find substring in it's responce. It's says 
**TypeError: argument of type 'FileModifiedEvent' is not iterable**

Original quickstart code for watchdog gives me logger report, but I don't find a way to find substring in logger that is not in the .txt file

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
```

So instead I wrote my own class, but it gives me that TypeError

```
    class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        def on_modified(self, event):
            test = 'mp4' in event
            print(test)
```

How to work with event as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [src_path](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEvent.src_path) attribute of `FileSystemEvent`:

```
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        test = 'mp4' in event.src_path
        print(test)
```